# C# / .NET - operator AS performance/approach

Tags: c#, as-operator

Im working on a e-commerce sort of application.

Entities are:

- `Product` with `List<Expense> Expenses`
- `Expense` with `Description` props which is referring to packaging, transport, administrative costs etc.

I need to have at least 2 types of expenses:

1. Relative expense (amount in percentage, calculated off the product price) and
2. Absolute expense (amount in numbers)

What i tried doing is having an

- `abstract class Expense` with props: `Id`, `Description`.
- `class RelativeExpense : Expense` with `AmountInPercentage` *props* and
- `class AbsoluteExpense : Expense`with `Amount` *props*.

For calculating expenses I'm having a `GetTotalExpenseAmount(Product p)`  method:

```
public decimal GetTotalExpenseAmount(Product p)

{
  decimal totalExpenses = 0;
  foreach (var expense in p.Expenses)
  {
       if(expense.GetType() == typeof(RelativeExpense))
       {
           totalExpenses += p.BasePrice * (expense as RelativeExpense).AmountInPercentage / 100;
       }
       else if(expense.GetType() == typeof(AbsoluteExpense))
       {
          totalExpenses += (expense as AbsoluteExpense).Amount;
       }
                
  }

    return totalExpenses;
}
```

My question is, is this a good practice? Reason i'm asking is because AS operator is doing casting and i know that can be expensive performance-wise. Plus i will have a `Logger` which will print out all expanses for a single product and therefore this `foreach` with `as` operator will be used again.

Is there any other way i can achieve what i want, but with better/cleaner code and performance? Maybe different modeling? Any ideas how should i approach this?

Comment: You should read up on virtual methods.

Comment: Must read: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: The expensive part here is checking the type twice, with `GetType()` and then the cast.

Comment: Note that even before pattern matching  with the `is` operator (in C# 7.0), you could just use `var tmp = expense as RelativeExpense;` and then check `if (tmp != null)` instead of `GetType()` then `as`.

Answer (score 4):

Why casting can be expensive performance wise? I don't think so.

However, you can use the `is` operator here which also skips nulls:

```
foreach (var expense in p.Expenses)
{
   if(expense is RelativeExpense relativeExpense)
   {
       totalExpenses += p.BasePrice * relativeExpense.AmountInPercentage / 100;
   }
   else if(expense is AbsoluteExpense absoluteExpense)
   {
      totalExpenses += absoluteExpense.Amount;
   }         
}
```

Comment: A switch expression would remove the need to check the type twice. It would also make it easier to find missed cases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You mean twice because of the `is` in the `if` and the `is` in the `else if`? Are you sure that it's different with a [`switch` type pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement)? The type is not known at compile time.

Comment: Yes, but I'm more concerned with missed cases. A default `_=>0` makes it clear that any missed cases won't contribute. It's also easier to see what's handled compared to the original code that used `GetType()`

Comment: PS: That's why I'm anxiously waiting for DUs, and getting rather ... annoyed (to put it mildly) that they seem to be postponed yet again

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What are DUs?

Comment: @41686d6564 "Discriminated Union", see https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/113 and https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/discriminated-unions.md

Comment: @41686d6564 with a discriminated union the compiler itself would detect whether a case is missing. This means that if you added eg a `SpeculativeExpense` afterwards you'll get an error telling you it's not handled in `GetTotalExpenseAmount`. And vice-versa, you won't have to use a default clause when you *do* handle all cases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you provide a code with your solution with `switch case`? Not sure what should be in `switch` and what should be in `case` part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can uses the OOO Polymorphism. So the C# virtual/abstract methods.

```
public decimal GetTotalExpenseAmount(Product p)
{
  decimal totalExpenses = 0;
  foreach (var expense in p.Expenses)
  {
       totalExpenses += expense.GetPrice();
  }
  return totalExpenses;
}

public class Product {
    public string Name;
    public List<Expense> Expenses;
}

public abstract class Expense {
    public string Id;
    public string Description;
    
    public abstract int GetPrice();
}

public class RelativeExpense : Expense {
    public int AmountInPercentage;
    public int BasePrice;
    
    public override int GetPrice() {
        return BasePrice * AmountInPercentage / 100;
    }
}

public class AbsoluteExpense : Expense { 
    public int Amount;
    
    public override int GetPrice() {
        return Amount;
    }
}
```

One caveat I moved the `BasePrice` to `RelativeExpense` class.

Comment: This doesn't give the same result since the relative expense requires knowing the product  base price. I realise you have just moved that property into the expense object, but that is unlikely to be a good idea. For example, let's say you are storing the relative expense object in your DB as a tax increase. You may want to use the object against multiple products, all with different base prices.

Comment: This is one case where polymorphism is a problem, not a solution. Who says `RelativeExpense` refers to a product's base price?

Comment: true, that was my assumption that it refers to base price. If it can't be moved then solution proposed by @Tim Schmelter is the way to go

Comment: Actually, I'm not a fan of Tim's answer either, would much rather see a switch expression as suggested by @Panagiotis. My rule of thumb is generally - if there is an `else` statement, then there's likely a better way to write that code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a single class with `IsRelative` property:

```
class Expense 
{
    (...)
    public bool IsRelative {get;}
    public decimal AmountInPercentage {get;}
    public decimal Amount {get;
}
(...)
foreach (var expense in p.Expenses)
{
    if(expense.IsRelative)
    {
        totalExpenses += p.BasePrice * expense.AmountInPercentage / 100;
    }
    else
    {
        totalExpenses += (expense as AbsoluteExpense).Amount;
    }            
}
```

or even

```
class Expense 
{
    (...)
    public bool IsRelative {get;}
    public decimal Amount {get;}
}

(...)

foreach (var expense in p.Expenses)
{
    if(expense.IsRelative)
    {
        totalExpenses += p.BasePrice * expense.Amount / 100;
    }
    else
    {
        totalExpenses += expense.Amount;
    }            
}
```